# What is the significance of Erik's nude scene?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

In [Thor: The Dark World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor%3a_The_Dark_World), what is the significance of the Erik's nude scene? Is it just for comedy effect? But if I remember correctly he justified it, but I don't understand the point. Even he was shown pant-less again in another scene. Is there any justification for it or just a comedy oriented non-justified scene?

Comment: Are you asking what he was actually doing there at *Stonehenge* and why he was so crazy? If you're just asking why he was nude, then that was just to emphasize his craziness. But why he was slightly crazy or fanatic I can't tell right away, maybe his "occupation" by *Loki* didn't go without side effects or maybe he just got a bit more excentric and fanatic about his research than normal.

Comment: @ChristianRau the work he was doing in Stonehenge  was not really that crazy and made sense later too but i didn't got the point of nude scene.

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"the work he was doing in Stonehenge was not really that crazy"* - No, but his way of carrying out the work was, especially his nudity and his disoriented behaviour.

Comment: I would add that this is an homage to a [famous quote](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If%20one%20studies%20too%20zealously,%20one%20easily%20loses%20his%20pants.%22%20--Albert%20Einstein&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=If%20one%20studies%20too%20zealously,%20one%20easily%20loses%20his%20pants.&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) by Albert Einstein: "If one studies too zealously, one easily loses his pants."

Comment: I wonder if we would be having this question if it was Natalie Portman's nude scene!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I believe that it was simply to show that he really have lost his mind. But that pants-less scene was done when he seemed completely sane, thus it seemed as if it's because of his natural queerness. Indeed yes, I think it was mentioned that Erik Selvig's mind hasn't completely returned sane after Loki invaded his mind. To quote Selvig himself:

> I had a god in my mind.

In addition, Selvig also said something like this:

> Finally, The world is crazier than I am.

It shows that he is fully aware that he is crazy, and someone who can asses himself as insane, is, usually, someone who still retain a degree of sanity. This is completely different in behavior than what he did at Stonehenge, suggesting that it was indeed an action that was completely not deliberate. He didn't seem to show any shame or regret in doing that, though, which I guess attributes itself to the partial madness.